# How to specify chef_environment for chef local mode (chef-client -z)

Tags: chef-infra, chef-zero

I have copied chef files from my chef server to a local client node, under `~/.chef`, i have all environments under `~/.chef/environments`, e.g. `development.rb`, `production.rb`, etc.

When i run `chef-client -z -E development -r 'recipe[cookbook_foo::recipe_bar]'` from under `~/.chef/` i get this error:

```
================================================================================
Error expanding the run_list:
================================================================================

Unexpected API Request Failure:
-------------------------------
Object not found: http://localhost:8889/environments/development
```

If i run the command without `-E development` everything works fine. However, i need to pass the environment name, because `#{node.chef_environment}` variable is used in that chef recipe. Google didn't provide me with an answer on this one :/

I'm using chef client 11.16.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Chef Zero doesn't understand the `.rb` DSL files. You'll need to convert your environment files to `.json` to use them with Chef Zero.

Comment: Great thanks! I converted the files and now everything works! :)